# npm start not working in create-react-app: missing script:start

Tags: reactjs, npm, create-react-app, npm-scripts

I tried to update my version of create-react-app by doing this:

> If you've previously installed create-react-app globally via npm
>   install -g create-react-app, we recommend you uninstall the package
>   using npm uninstall -g create-react-app to ensure that npx always uses
>   the latest version.

But now, when I run npm start, i get an error message:

```
missing script: start
```

But in the `package.json` from my app, i found the start script:

```
{
  "name": "dropzone-montessori",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "^16.12.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.12.0",
    "react-scripts": "3.2.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

Anybody knows what's happening?

Comment: Try `npx react-scripts start` to verify that react-scripts is installed locally. If not, then you will have to run npm install again.

Comment: Please confirm that you're in the same directory as your package.json file.

Comment: just install the packages again using npm install and then start the node module (npm start)

Comment: It only worked when I re-installed the application with yarn